# Why I am not able to login when I use mysql admin password for phpMyAdminor bypass login screen when I set 'AllowNoPassword'] to TRUE?

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin

Why I am not able to login when I use MySQL admin password for phpMyAdminor bypass login screen when I set `AllowNoPassword` to `TRUE`?

Here what I did:

Environment:

- OS Fedora Linux 22(64 bit) with graphical user interface
- wembin version 1.760.
- PHP 5.6.13
- Maria DB server (MySQL) version 10.0.21
- Installed phpMyAdmin-4.5.0.2. for Fedora Linux 22(64 bit).

Following steps I used to install phpMyAdmin-4.5.0.2:

1. #dnf –y update
2. #yum install phpMyAdmin mariadb-server
3. Add user
   #addusr phpmy
   #passwd phpmy
4. Modify the phpmyadmin directory’s ownership to phpmy user
   chown _r phpmy.apache phpMyAdmin
5. systemctl restart httpd
6. http://localhost/phpMyAdmin
7. At login prompt not able to login using phpmy/ phpmy as user ID and password.

Comment: To add a bit more detail from our private discussion -- and please correct me if I'm wrong -- the error message is that phpMyAdmin is not allowing connections without a password (due to AllowNoPassword being set to true). Also, you've also tried removing the packaged version entirely and installing from the tarball at phpmyadmin.net and still your modifications to config.inc.php don't change the resulting message. Sound right?

Comment: Also, as an aside, adding the system user for phpmy and modifying the directory permissions shouldn't be needed, but also shouldn't have hurt anything.

Comment: Yes, installing from the tarball at web directory such as var/www/html/ does not resolve the problem. In addition added user with admin privilege in MySQL server and added the same user to have access to phpMyAdmin directory. Setting AllowNoPassword to TRUE or False does not matter, I simply not allowed to pass login screen no matter what userId/Password I use. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Your help is greatly appreciated- Thanks

Comment: And regardless of what you try the only error message you see is `Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)`, correct?

Comment: Yes, when I set AllowNoPassword to "TRUE".